# Applescript Access Print and Scan

Tags: scripting, applescript

I'm getting my feet wet with AppleScript. It seems pretty neat, but totally different than the kind of scripting I'm used to working with. My problem lies here:

I want to open up System Preferences and then Print&Scan.

I can do it for many other preference panes, but not Print&Scan. For example,

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell
```

will get me to the preference pane for sound. How would I open Print&Scan?

Also, is there a place that lists all the panes you can use? I looked in the Applescript dictionary, but couldn't seem to find where they might be? Is that something listed in the dictionary?

Thank you in advance,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find the particular preference pane I want to use, for example in the **/System/Library/PreferencePanes** folder, and look up the bundle identifier (in the **Info.plist** file) - in this case it would be **com.apple.preference.printfax**.

Comment: Just to add to his answer. I at first did not realize that PrintAndScan.prefPane was a folder, but you can cd into it. Then keep going into directories until you get to the Info.plist. Then inside that file is the bundle identifier. Thank you for this live saver!